# Jump to specific row in jsgrid

Tags: jquery, html, .net, asp.net-web-api, jsgrid

I am using JS Grid (http://js-grid.com) to render data in grid view.

My grid has multiple pages. After inserting a row, I want to jump to the page which contains newly added row and highlight the added row.

Does jsgrid provide any option for it. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

1. since you are doing server-side pagination (as appears from your comments) compute the page index of the inserted item, knowing the page size and ordering.
2. Insert server script can return inserted item data. Add a field to the item data (e.g. `pageIndex`) and set it to the page index computed at (1).
3. jsGrid has [onItemInserted](http://js-grid.com/docs/#oniteminserted) callback, which accepts inserted item data as `args.item`. In this callback use [openPage](http://js-grid.com/docs/#openpagepageindex) method to open the page of the inserted item.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

var LastRowID = $($("#GridID").find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:last")).attr('id');

$("#"+LastRowID).effect("highlight", {}, 2000);

Comment: After inserting, I am sorting records in ascending order. Also, I am doing server side pagination. In that case, will this code work.?

Comment: @Venkateshwari, I think you are talking about another grid component, not http://js-grid.com